# Execution Flow of Actuator

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

I have Actuator implemented in spring boot application and these actuator code are executed when i'm running main class from some ide like Eclipse but when i'm running .jar from terminal this code is not executed at run time. Is their any difference on running main class or running jar in spring boot actuator ?

I have tried by putting some sysout and its getting printed when running main class but not when running jar file.

```
@Component
public class MicroServiceInfoConfiguror implements HealthIndicator, InfoContributor {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MicroserviceHealthIndicator.class);

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
        int a = 10/0;
        System.out.println("*****************************Info***************************************************");
    }

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        int a = 10/0;
        System.out.println("Here in health indicator..........................***********************************************");
        int errorCode = check(); // perform some specific health check
        if (errorCode != 0) {
            return Health.down().withDetail("Error Code", errorCode).build();
        }
        return Health.up().build();
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    private int check() {
        Integer count = null;
        try {
            Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select count(1) FROM system");
            List results = query.getResultList();
            for (Object next : results) {
                count = ((BigInteger) next).intValue();
            }
            logger.info("Health Check:" + count);
            System.out.println("Health Check:" + count);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception occurred in check()", e);
        }
        return (count != null && count.intValue() > 0) ? 0 : -1;
    }

}
```

It should print all sysout in both the cases

Comment: are you sure that your class is included in the JAR?

Comment: Yes. Any SYSOUT in main class is printing in console (just for reconfirmation)